# CSS not working for div created within JS

Tags: javascript

I was not aware you could even do this.. Anyway these div classes have been created within the JS stylesheet but when I attempt to change the cursor css styling for .pl-list it does not work
The custom cursor is working on the .pl-container overlay but not the individual pl-list items

I am creating a page with an audio player and am referencing this pen https://codepen.io/k-ivan/pen/pJMLmJ

JS

```
var

tplList =
        '<li class="pl-list" data-track="{count}">'+
          '<div class="pl-list__track">'+
            '<div class="pl-list__icon"></div>'+
            '<div class="pl-list__eq">'+
              '<div class="eq">'+
                '<div class="eq__bar"></div>'+
                '<div class="eq__bar"></div>'+
                '<div class="eq__bar"></div>'+
              '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
          '</div>'+
          '<div class="pl-list__title">{title}</div>'+
          '<button class="pl-list__remove">'+
            '<svg fill="#000000" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">'+
                '<path d="M6 19c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h8c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V7H6v12zM19 4h-3.5l-1-1h-5l-1 1H5v2h14V4z"/>'+
                '<path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>'+
            '</svg>'+
          '</button>'+
        '</li>',

pl = create('div', {
    'className': 'pl-container',
    'id': 'pl',
    'innerHTML': '<ul class="pl-ul">' + (!isEmptyList() ? html.join('') : '<li class="pl-list--empty">PlayList is empty</li>') + '</ul>'
  });
```

CSS

```
.pl-list {
    cursor: url('...'),auto;
}
```

Secondly, I am trying to apply an CSS3 transition to the pl-container on opening but I just cannot seem to be able to apply any additional css to these div classes

Does anyone have any suggestions? I understand this is a lot of code to look through so again my apologies

Comment: Too many unknown / undefined things here. What are `create()`, `isEmptyList()` and `html`? You also never do anything with `tplList`.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this, it works in my case.

```
var tplList = '<li class="pl-list" data-track="{count}">'+
                  '<div class="pl-list__track">'+
                      '<div class="pl-list__icon"></div>'+
                      '<div class="pl-list__eq">'+
                          '<div class="eq">'+
                              '<div class="eq__bar"></div>'+
                              '<div class="eq__bar"></div>'+
                              '<div class="eq__bar"></div>'+
                          '</div>'+
                      '</div>'+
                  '</div>'+
                  '<div class="pl-list__title">{title}</div>'+
                  '<button class="pl-list__remove">'+
                      '<svg fill="#000000" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">'+
                          '<path d="M6 19c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h8c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V7H6v12zM19 4h-3.5l-1-1h-5l-1 1H5v2h14V4z"/>'+
                          '<path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>'+
                      '</svg>'+
                  '</button>'+
              '</li>',
```

Comment: What did you change?